# How to check if object has property that can be assigned to?

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to check if an object has a property that can be assigned to?

Currently, I'm using:

```js
const obj = new MyClass();
if ('property' in obj) {
  obj['property'] = value;
}
```

But, that results in an error if `MyClass` is defined like:

```js
class MyClass {
  get property() {
    return 'value';
  }
}
```

In which case the `property` does exist, but it cannot be assigned to:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property quickRead of [object Object] which has only a getter
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./lib/model/construct.ts:23:29)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at construct (webpack-internal:///./lib/model/construct.ts:16:27)
    at new Subscription (webpack-internal:///./lib/model/subscription.ts:55:65) 
    at new Message (webpack-internal:///./lib/model/message.ts:40:5)
    at Function.fromFirestore (webpack-internal:///./lib/model/message.ts:100:12)
    at Function.fromFirestoreDoc (webpack-internal:///./lib/model/message.ts:114:29)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./lib/api/update/messages.ts:19:64)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at updateMessages (webpack-internal:///./lib/api/update/messages.ts:16:26)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async updateAccount (webpack-internal:///./pages/api/account.ts:55:5)
    at async account (webpack-internal:///./pages/api/account.ts:88:7)
    at async apiResolver (/home/ubuntu/repos/hammock/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js:8:1)
```

Is there a way that I can use the `in` keyword to check that a property can be assigned to?

Answer (score 1):

Use [getOwnPropertyDescriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor):

Example from the docs (note the `writable` property in the output):

```js
const object1 = {
  property1: 42
};

const descriptor1 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object1, 'property1');


//For class objects, we need to check for the objects prototype. If there is multilevel inheritance, then you will have to check prototypes one by one
const descriptor2= Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(object2), 'property1');


console.log(descriptor1);
```

descriptor1 will have a lot of keys, some more relevant in your case such as getter and setter.

Comment: Does this approach work with Class syntax?

Comment: I tried this, and no it doesn't. If I check on the .__proto__, it does seem to work though.

Answer (score -1):

You are able to check exist of a property in an object by **hasOwnProperty** , for example :

```js
cons myObject = {
    propertyA: "property"
};

if (myObject.hasOwnProperty("propertyA")){
    //do something
};
```

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` tells you if the property is attached directly at the object you are working with or if it is an inherited property. It doesn't have anything to do with whether you can write to it.